# Add folder to SVN repository without checking out or committing?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When using something like TortoiseSVN, you can use it's repo-browser to browse repositories and do stuff. One thing you can do is create directories in the repository. Normally you would have to checkout the repo, then create and add the directories and finally commit them to accomplish this. But you are able to do it in the repo-browser in one command.

Is it possible to do something similar from the command-line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do `svn mkdir mynewdirectory` then it will create mynewdirectory on your local machine and only update the repository the next time that you commit.

However, if you do `svn mkdir svn://svnrepo.my.big.business.com/myproject/mydirectory` then the directory is created on the repository. You can use this URL format with any svn commands, for instance you can use `svn copy` to make a copy of project on the repository by using the URL form for both the from and the to directories.

Comment: our SVN implementation also required a commit message for this action - so syntax would be svn mkdir mynewdirectory -m "mycommitmessage"

Answer (score 5):

`svn import` can immediately commit a local directory, or `svn mkdir` if you want to create a directory in the repo without any local file involvement.